# Cannot open include file: 'dxgi1_2.h': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-c++, directx-11, dxgi

I am including the header file "dxgi1_2.h" in my VC++ code & I see that I'm getting the  error.

```
Cannot open include file: 'dxgi1_2.h': No such file or directory
```

I know this is because, I need to install something from MSFT related to DX11. (Is the Win8 SDK enough for this header file)
Can anyone kindly let me know how do I fix this error?

Comment: Did you download the directX SDK?

Comment: It is DirectX Graphics Infrastructure 1.2. It is hard to tell what part of abundant Microsoft's online documentation you do not understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 8 and .NET Framework 4.5  v8.0a should be enough, because I found it with everything in the sdk's include directory.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You should probably re-check your include paths in project settings: Project->Settings->C/C++->include. Sometimes even giving correct paths might not work, in which case you need to restart Visual Studio.